# Не работает js скрипт

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно перемещать div по нажатию на кнопку. Написал следующий код, но он не работает, квадрат остается на своем месте.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  button.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("cube").style.left = 100 + 'px';
  }
</script>


<div id="cube" style="left: 10px; width: 150px; height: 150px; background: green;"></div>
<a href="" id="button">Переместить куб вправо!</a>
```

Comment: Примите хотя бы некоторые из данных Вам ответов.

Comment: скрипт загружатеся раньше чем разметка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте местами скрипт и разметку.

```html
<a href="" id="button">Переместить куб вправо!</a>
<div id="cube" style="left: 10px; width: 150px; height: 150px; background: green;position:absolute;top:35px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  button.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("cube").style.left = 100 + 'px';
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

или

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    button.onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("cube").style.left = 100 + 'px';
      return false;
    }
  });
</script>

<a href="" id="button">Переместить куб вправо!</a>
<div id="cube" style="left: 10px; width: 150px; height: 150px; background: green;position:absolute;top:35px;"></div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо. То есть, js должен быть в самом конце?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда да, если он не подгружается в теге <head>

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда Хм. На этот вопрос нет однозначного ответа. Свойство `window.button` появится только после того, как браузер прочитает элемент с `id="button"`. Ваш код, который назначает `button.onclick = ` выполняется в том месте, в котором он написан. Вы можете или сделать как в ответе, или завернуть Ваш код в `window.addEventListener("load", ...)` - то есть отложить его выполнение до окончания загрузки страницы.

Comment: @Igor если бы он подгружал файл в <head> <script scr="....."></script></head> , результат был бы другим)

Comment: @SonicMyst тогда `window.addEventListener("load", function() {...});`